# ORA-01489: Oracle - ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I work on this query and get this error:

> Oracle - ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Some one please help to solve this issue

```
SELECT LISTAGG(RCRDNUM) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RCRDNUM)
FROM (SELECT (ERR.RCRDNUM || ',') AS RCRDNUM
      FROM TABLENAME ERR
      INNER JOIN (SELECT UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR('No value present for CNTRY_CD column for the record',
                                             '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) ERR_MSG
                  FROM DUAL
                  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('No value present for CNTRY_CD column for the record',
                                           '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                      IS NOT NULL) ERRMSG_P
      ON (UPPER(ERR.ERRMSG) = ERRMSG_P.ERR_MSG
          OR 'No value present for CNTRY_CD column for the record' IS NULL))
```

Comment: Is the result of your `listagg` potentially more than 4000 characters?  If so, you can't use `listagg` (or you would need to provide a filter in your inline view that reduces the number of rows being returned).  If you need to generate a longer string, you could write your own aggregate function that handles `clob` data types (there are a few implementations online).

Comment: @JustinCave - ... or use `xmlagg()`

Answer (score 2):

If the aggregate list is a string longer than 4000 characters, the string needs to be a CLOB, and you can't use `listagg()`. However, you can use `xmlagg()`, which does not have the 4000 character limit. The result must be a CLOB though - and it is cast as CLOB in the solution.

. Here is a proof-of-concept; I will let you adapt it to your situation.

```
with a (id,val) as (select 10, 'x' from dual union all select 20, 'abc' from dual)
select listagg(val, ',') within group (order by id) as l_agg,
       rtrim( xmlcast( xmlagg( xmlelement(e, val || ',') order by id) as clob), ',')
       as clob_agg
from   a
;
```

**Output**

```
L_AGG      CLOB_AGG
---------- ----------
x,abc      x,abc
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle's SQL queries, strings (columns of type VARCHAR) are limited to 4000 characters. Obviously, your query creates longer strings and therefore fails. This can easily happen with `LISTAGG`.

Should your query really return such long strings? If not, you need to work on your query.

If you really need values longer than 4000 characters, you can try to use CLOB instead of VARCHAR by using a custom user-defined aggregation function. Tom Kyte has an [example](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402#29842804516386) in one of his questions.